# icc on dataframe with row for each rater

Tags: r

Let me start off with saying I'm completely new to R and trying to figure out how to run icc on my specific dataset which might be a bit different then normally.

The dataset looks as follows

```
+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    date    | measurement_type | measurement1 | measurement2 | measurement3 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 25-04-2020 |                1 |         15.5 |         34.3 |         43.2 |
| 25-04-2020 |                2 |         21.2 |         12.3 |          2.2 |
| 25-04-2020 |                3 |         16.2 |          9.6 |         43.3 |
| 25-04-2020 |                4 |           27 |            1 |            6 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

now I want to do icc on all of those rows since each row stands for a different rater. It should leave the `date` and `measurement_type` columns out.

can someone point me in the right direction, I have absolutely no idea how to go about this.

**------- EDIT -------**
I exported the actual dataset that will come out with some test data.
Which is available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qUUI1Ul4mZmcBzdMsAsR3usIt6smR6QZ)

The 2 important sheets here are the first and third.
The first contains all the participants of the research and the third contains all 4 different reports for each participant. The code I have so far just to tie each report to the correct participant;

```
library("XLConnect")
library("sqldf")
library("irr")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")

# Load in Workbook
wb = loadWorkbook("Measuring.xlsx")
# Load in Worksheet
# Sheet 1 = Study Results
# Sheet 3 = Meetpunten
records = readWorksheet(wb, sheet=1)
reports = readWorksheet(wb, sheet=3)

for (record in 1:nrow(records)) {
  recordId = records[record, 'Record.Id']
  participantReports = sqldf(sprintf("select * from reports where `Record.Id` = '%s'", recordId))

  baselineReport = sqldf("select * from participantReports where measurement_type = '1'")
  drinkReport = sqldf("select * from participantReports where measurement_type = '2'")
  regularReport = sqldf("select * from participantReports where measurement_type = '3'")
  exerciseReport = sqldf("select * from participantReports where measurement_type = '4'")
}
```

Comment: what is the package used for icc

Comment: @akrun I'm using `irr` atm

Comment: I would join the two sheets or objects (records & reports) by recordID and then apply a function by group, with the groups being defined by measurement_type. This can be done using `dplyr` with a `left_join` function and a `group_by` in  a pipe followed by a `summarize` function..

Comment: @PaulvanOppen could you make this an answer with preferably an example on how to do it. that way if it's correct I can accept it and assign the bounty to you as well. This might also help other people who run into the same issue

Comment: NoSixties, should not be a problem. I had a look at your xlsx sheet. You have many columns in `Meetpunten`; can you indicate which columns contain the observations you would like to use for ICC calculation?

Comment: @PaulvanOppen basically everything after the `time` column is relevant

Comment: I thought your issue is how to reshape the data in the xlsx file sheets to the table listed in your question rather than getting the `measurement` columns from the object and passing them to the `irr` function. The sheet `meetpunten` already has observations as rows (with date) and variables as columns (`PWC_value`, `line_length` etc). It may be that e.g. `measurement 1` is some function of your `meetpunten` such as `mean`. But that would be very straightforward to code. 
Is that not sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Since in your data each row stands for a different rater, but the icc function in the irr package needs the raters to be columns, you can ignore the two first columns of your table, transpose it and run icc.

So, assuming this table:

```
+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    date    | measurement_type | measurement1 | measurement2 | measurement3 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 25-04-2020 |                1 |         15.5 |         34.3 |         43.2 |
| 25-04-2020 |                2 |         21.2 |         12.3 |          2.2 |
| 25-04-2020 |                3 |         16.2 |          9.6 |         43.3 |
| 25-04-2020 |                4 |           27 |            1 |            6 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

is stored in a variable called `data`, i would do it like this:

```
data2 = data.matrix(data[,-c(1,2)]) # generates the dataset without the first two columns
```

`data2` is this table:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| measurement1 | measurement2 | measurement3 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|         15.5 |         34.3 |         43.2 |
|         21.2 |         12.3 |          2.2 |
|         16.2 |          9.6 |         43.3 |
|           27 |            1 |            6 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Then:

```
data2 = t(data2) # transpose data2 so as to have raters in the columns and their ratings in each line
icc(data2) # here i'm not bothering with the parameters, but you should explore the appropriate icc parameters for your needs.
```

should generate a correct run.